# bluetooth issue i7 3rd gen ubuntu 20.04lts

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, blueman

```
alpharays@alpharays-pc:~$ sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service
Synchronizing state of bluetooth.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable bluetooth
alpharays@alpharays-pc:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Aug 29 13:47:49 alpharays-pc systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Blueto…ped.
Aug 29 13:48:38 alpharays-pc systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Blueto…ped.
Aug 29 13:49:31 alpharays-pc systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Blueto…ped.
Aug 29 13:49:38 alpharays-pc systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Blueto…ped.
Aug 29 15:28:37 alpharays-pc systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Blueto…ped.
Aug 29 16:03:10 alpharays-pc systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Blueto…ped.
Aug 29 16:07:50 alpharays-pc systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Blueto…ped.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
alpharays@alpharays-pc:~$ hcitool dev
Devices:
alpharays@alpharays-pc:~$ sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service
Synchronizing state of bluetooth.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable bluetooth
alpharays@alpharays-pc:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
Starting bluetooth (via systemctl): bluetooth.service.
alpharays@alpharays-pc:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-08-29 16:08:36 IST; 4s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 6814 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9337)
     Memory: 1.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─6814 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Aug 29 16:08:36 alpharays-pc systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Aug 29 16:08:36 alpharays-pc bluetoothd[6814]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Aug 29 16:08:36 alpharays-pc systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Aug 29 16:08:36 alpharays-pc bluetoothd[6814]: Starting SDP server
Aug 29 16:08:36 alpharays-pc bluetoothd[6814]: Bluetooth management interfac…zed
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

still blueman manager showing daemon not started or adapter not found .

Comment: lsusb , not showing and bluetooth

Comment: So there is no Bluetooth ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 it was working perfect with windows.

Comment: Post output of `lsusb` then.